# is App Linking working? if export="false"

Tags: java, android, android-deep-link, android-app-links

App Linking not working if export="false"(for security reasons we have to keep false) in app linking activity in android 12 or higher versions. here app linking verification done.

if we change **export="true"** app linking working fine in android 12 also
if we change **export ="false"** app linking not working

Answer (score 1):

The `export` property makes your activity visible to other apps, and also makes it visible to linking. If you have any activity that needs to be exposed via deep linking or have intent filters other apps can use, those activities need to have `export="true'`. This is intended behavior.